# Как организовать структуру проекта .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net

Я новичок в этом деле, возможно вопрос покажется глупым, но для меня это важно. Начал изучать .NET Core, для веб приложений, и при создании проекта в Visial Studio там помимо главного файла с кодом С#, есть ещё папки `bin` и `obj`. Я гуглил насчёт этого, но так и не понял, каким образом создавать проект .NET с такими файлами, и как правильно его структурировать?

Допустим у меня есть главный файл, это точка входа программы C# (там где находится класс с методом `main`) и в том же каталоге находится папка `modules`, там у меня будут находиться разные модули. Правильный ли это подход? Или нужно эту папку создавать где-то в `bin` или `obj`?.

Так как я раньше писал на питоне, там всё просто и понятно, создал папку, в ней файл, и ничего другого там нет, кроме того, что создал ты. На С# нужно создавать какие-то файлы в `bin` или `obj`, или эти папки не нужно трогать вообще?

В общем, я думаю что структура проекта может выглядеть так:

- main.cs (`main` method)
- /bin
- /obj
- /modules1

  - someModule.cs
  - someModule2.cs
- /modules2

  - someModule.cs

Но не уверен в этом, верно ли это? Нужно ли кидать файлы `bin` и `obj` на гитхаб, или их нужно игнорировать? Буду очень благодарен за объяснение, заранее благодарю !)

Comment: Вас не должно волновать, что там в файловой системе лежит. У вас есть проводник решения (Solution Explorer справа, в студии), организуйте свое решение там. Папки bin и obj - служебные, они не относятся к самому решению. Первая - для собранного решения, вторая для промежуточных файлов, требуемых для сборки. Папки bin и obj кидать на гитхаб не нужно, добавьте их в .gitignore.

Comment: У вас в родительской папке еще `.sln` файл есть, вот его надо кидать на гитхаб, то есть его и папку с решением.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо за ответ! Тоесть, в проводнике решения я могу организовать ту структуру проекта которую я описал выше? Папка `/modules`, и в ней можно хранить свои модули, а главный файл в корне?

Comment: Там уж как вам удобнее. Способ организации `.cs` файлов никак не влияет на собранное решение, другими словами от того что вы туда-сюда переложите файлы, приложение будет работать так, как работало до перекладывания.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой краткий и информативный ответ, я искал много информации об этом, находил не то, или что-то, что я не до конца понимал, а оказалось всё на много проще !

Comment: Вы еще неверный термин выбрали "модули", модуль для приложения - это библиотека, другой проект (`.cproj`), результатом сборки которого является например `.dll` библотека. Проект может содержвать много cs файлов. А вот каждый cs файл должен содержать в себе один `class` и называться так, как называется класс. Например у вас есть класс `public class Program`, значит файл должен назваться `Program.cs`. Есть еще интерфейсы, но суть с ними та же. Так принято делать в больших проектах (класс = cs файл), но это на самом деле на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: 1) создаете проект по шаблону asp.net core 2) Там уже есть начальная разбива по папкам, добавляете нужные папки вам. Имейте ввиду, что для asp.net MVC проектов структура папок для представлений имеет значение - об этом можно почитать в любой книге по asp.net MVC.

Comment: @tym32167 казалось бы, при чем здесь ASP.NET Core MVC, то есть какое оно имеет отношение к вопросу. Но вы совершенно правы.

Comment: @aepot долгий день. Даже нверное долгий год. Каша в голове. Так что не обессудьте :)

Comment: @aepot в вопросе есть маленькое упоминание `«для веб приложений»`.

Comment: @tym32167, тоесть для веб приложений, веб серверов, лучше использовать ASP.NET Core чем .NET Core? Столько разных решений, в начале непросто определиться что тебе действительно подходит ..)

Comment: @AndreiBohumok в мире .Net есть сейчас две платформы, которые выполняют написанный и скомпилированный код: .Net Framework и .Net Core. При этом .Net Core основан на .Net Framework, но мультиплатформенный. Писать вы будете в обоих на одинаковом C#, просто есть пара особенностей в конфигах, компиляции и пакетах. А вот ASP.NET MVC Framework (для .Net Framework) и ASP.NET Core MVC (для .Net Core) - это готовый шаблон проекта для веб приложения со всей нужной функциональностью. Можно глянуть тут https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/3.1.php или читать с начала https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/

Comment: @AndreiBohumok но если вы только начали изучать C#, то можете продолжать работать с ним и потом уже начать изучать проекты с использованием шаблона проекта ASP.Net Core MVC.

Comment: @AlexKrass, спасибо за пояснение. Я как раз изучаю основные вещи в С#, стараюсь постепенно всё узнавать, и создавая консольную программу, написал код, который с помощью `File.WriteAllText("main.txt", text);`, записывает текст в файл `main.txt` (который находится в корневой папке в месте с файлом где находится класс с методом `main`), я заметил, что текст не записывается в файл `main.txt`, но создаётся новый, в папке `bin`.  Так и должно быть? В продакшн там тоже файлы созданные хранят? Выглядит неудобно, или я что-то не понял? Гуглил, там писали о приложениях Windows, но что насчёт веб пр. ?

Comment: @AndreiBohumok платформа .Net шире, чем может показаться. Она запускает на выполнение не сам код языков C#, VB, F# и другие, а специальный промежуточный код MSIL. Для этого компилятор берет исходный код на C# и компилирует его в MSIL, файлы которого потом можно будет выполнить. Следовательно, эти скомпилированные файлы надо где-то хранить, вот и появляется папка bin (её можно удалить и при компиляции она появится снова). Поскольку ваша программа с вашим *.exe выполняется в папке ./bin/Debug/ или ./bin/Release/, то и main.txt появляется там же. Это же содержимое, которое отдается пользователю.

Comment: @AlexKrass, Если простыми словами, то `bin` - Это некий контейнер для конечного приложения, то же и с ASP.NET Core? Все фото и текстовые файлы с которыми должна работать программа или будущий сервер в продакшн, должны находиться в `bin`?  Например если у меня будет сервер, и он будет сохранять фото, которые пользователь выбрал, значит, он их будет хранить в папке `bin` - и это корректно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118520/discussion-between-alex-krass-and-andrei-bohumok).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Негласно принято правило, что структура каталогов проекта в файловой системе соответствует пространствам имен. Например, пространство имен `X.Y.Z` соответствует `X/Y/Z` в структуре каталогов. Это позволяет проще ориентироваться в проекте даже без установленной на компьютере IDE. Это значит, если у вас каталог modules, файлы в ней должны содержать `namespace modules`.

На деле же "modules" является плохим именем для каталога и пространства имен. Если это не пример, а реальное имя, поменяйте его. Для начала, идентификаторы пространств имен пишут с большой буквы. Кроме того, имя должно быть осмысленным. Обычно принято либо именование по архитектурным слоям в соответствии с принятой методологией проектирования (MyProject.Models, MyProject.Views), либо по функционалу (MyProject.Calculation, MyProject.DataAccess). Отступления возможны, когда в одном пространстве имен слишком много файлов, и каталог приходится дробить далее, либо когда пространства имен слишком длинны и создание каталогов с такими же именами приведет к ошибкам на отдельных компьютерах.

Все эти правила неписаные, Framework Design Guidelines не покрывают структуру исходников, так как они видны только разработчику. В отдельных организациях могут существовать свои стандарты по структуре проектов.

> Нужно ли кидать файлы bin и obj на гитхаб, или их нужно игнорировать?

Ответ на этот вопрос сразу станет ясным, если посмотреть на стандартный файл .gitignore, который Github рекомендует для Visual Studio: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

> ```
> # Build results
> ...
> [Bb]in/
> [Oo]bj/
> ```

Эти каталоги относятся к тем, которые почти всегда игнорируют, так как они содержат выходные и промежуточные файлы сборки. Рекомендуется перед заливкой в Git проекта, тем более большого, не гадать, какие файлы игнорировать, а добавлять стандартный файл .gitignore для Visual Studio, а затем уже штучно по ситуации разрешать какие-то игнорируемые каталоги, если они нужны в индексе. В противном случае есть вероятность, что размер репозитория будет раздуваться из-за мусора в индексе, который вы не предусмотрели.

См. также: [How do you organize your projects? - Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/40394/328742)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, если я правильно понял, в проектах С# термин который я использовал - модуль, это не корректно. Проект С# разделяется на папки, в них есть файлы с классами, которые выполняют какую-то задачу. Допустим у меня есть в корне файл `validators`, в нем есть файлы `password`, `email` - то пространство имён у них будет `validators`? Если так, то все классы находящиеся в `validators` должны иметь уникальное имя. А если в файле `validators` будет ещё несколько файлов с какими-то классами, то пространство имён в этих файлах нужно назвать так же, как и каталог в котором они находятся?

Comment: На сколько большим может быть каталог с файлами `.cs` ? Ведь как вы говорили, если будет слишком много вложенных папок, а в них файлов, импортировать их будет сложно: `MyProject.User.Validators.Password...`

Comment: @AndreiBohumok Просто от того, что вы добавите файл в подкаталог, он не станет в другом пространстве имен, для этого содержимое файла должно быть заключено в блок namespace ... {}. Если вы создадите файл через студию, он ее автоматически сгенерирует с именем вида `(ИмяПроекта).(ИмяПодкаталога)`. Если создавать в проводнике, это надо будет сделать вручную. Да, все классы в пространстве имен должны иметь уникальное имя.

Comment: Посмотрите примеры open source проектов, например https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src - так будет проще понять на наглядном примере, о чем я говорю. Насчет числа файлов в каталоге - в целях удобства, обычно лучше не делать больше 1000, тогда каталог невозможно будет просмотреть в веб-интерфейсе Github.

Comment: Если я импортирую два пространства имён в какой-то файл, допустим `using A` и `using B` - И в пространстве имён `А` и `В` будет класс с одинаковым именем, то будет ошибка? Тоесть нужно следить за тем, что бы пространства имён которые мы используем в файл, не имели класса с таким же именем.

Comment: Если взять другие языки, например питон, там можно импортировать два модуля `А` и `В`, и в них может быть класс с одинаковым именем, мы можем просто обращаться к ним вот так: `А.add(); B.add();`

Comment: @AndreiBohumok В C# все это также есть: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces#fully-qualified-names

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь в голове сложилось всё по полочкам :) !!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118521/discussion-between-andrei-bohumok-and-msdn-whiteknight).